# Migrating from localhost to live server redirecting error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cpanel

I am in the process of moving my localhost Drupal 7 site to the live site on the web. I have followed the steps below. I did install Drupal in a subdomain where it lives at example.org/drupal.

1) Clear your cache table

2)Export Database

3) Login to your Cpanel. Go to Mysql Database. Create a new database. (remember name of the database) and add a user to it. (remember username and password as you will required to use same in your settings.php file)

4)Now go to Phpmyadim from cpanel. Select the new database that you have created. Click on the import and upload that sql file that you created in step 4.
5)Check that you have same no. of tables in your new database (on server) as you were having on local server

5) Now go to your settings.php file sites/default/settings.php and change the name of database to new one that you created with username:password that you created for that database

6) Now use your ftp account and filezilla to transfer all the file on server

After completing all the steps when I go to mysite.com/drupal I am greeted with a "The page isn't redirecting properly" error. It shows that it is redirecting to http://example.org/drupal/install.php. After doing some research I found out that this is usually due to an error in settings.php. I have tried everything I can think of but still the error persists.

Here is my code in settings.php around line 180.

```
/* 
 * Database configuration format:
 * @code
 *   $databases['default']['default'] = array(
 *     'driver' => 'mysql',
 *     'database' => 'whiteoa_wob_newdesign',
 *     'username' => 'whiteoa_admin',
 *     'password' => '********',
 *     'host' => 'localhost',
 *     'prefix' => '',
 *   );
 */
```

I have also tried my database name and username without the whiteoa prefix. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there a base_url commented out in that file?

Comment: It is not commented out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities.

You need to set $base_url in settings.php to be yourdomain.com/drupal or you have an issue in your .htaccess file.

Try uncommenting RewriteBase /drupal in your .htaccess file or post it here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did as you said and unfortunately no change. To be specific I changed my base_url in settings.php around line 257.... # $base_url = 'mysite.org/drupal';  // NO trailing slash!

Comment: try an absolute url eg, your full domain.

Comment: No luck on the absolute URL. Is my database information correctly entered in? I'm not sure if I need to put the whiteoa prefix? I am also trying currently to share the htc access file but Stack overflow is not allowing me too. Not sure of the best way to share this.

Comment: the prefix is right, that's your cpanel username. You should be able to post it otherwise just put it on pastebin.com. Did you clear the cache after changing your settings file?

Comment: Here is a pastebin of my current settings.php file and htc access.http://pastebin.com/MPTAHDPa  I did clear the cache in firefox

Comment: Change: 'whiteoakbaptist.org/drupal' to http://whiteoakbaptist.org/drupal Also you should be clearing your drupal cache. If you have drush you can use drush cc all otherwise truncate the cache tables.

Comment: I changed my base url to ... $base_url = 'http://whiteoakbaptist.org/drupal';  // NO trailing slash! I also tried  $base_url = http://whiteoakbaptist.org/drupal;  // NO trailing slash!  No luck with either. I am looking into drush now that might take me a little while to get running. Thanks again for your help

Comment: just truncate the cache_* tables. Or clear the cache locally and then copy the DB up again. Everything looks correct now.

Comment: I truncated the cache_*tables from within phpmyadmin. The same issue still persists. Still just get the redirecting error. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This is all the code that I am currently working on.                                                                   $base_url = 'http://whiteoakbaptist.org/drupal';  // NO trailing slash!                                                              
    $databases['default']['default'] = array(
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'database' => 'whiteoa_wob_newdesign',
      'username' => 'whiteoa_admin',
      'password' => '*******',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'prefix' => '',
    );                                                             RewriteBase /drupal

Comment: Can you link me to the site?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too old to be answered but it might help somebody in the futur:

As i see you have a problem within your database settings.

Database settings should look like this:

```
$databases = array (
'default' => array (
'default' => array (
'database' => 'prefix_db_name',
'username' => 'prefix_db_user',
'password' => '******',
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => '',
'driver' => 'mysql',
'prefix' => '',
),
),
);
```